# I was trying to orient my repository in domain terms with mapstruct, but one method is giving me troubles

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, mapstruct

I was trying to convert some repositories to domain repositories, in a attempt of implementing a data mapper pattern but when i try to refartor some methods that implement crudRepository interfaces it say that the requiered value is list of products and im giving it a optional list of products but the value that i have to return in the method is Optional List of products this is the code of the method:

```
    @Override
    public Optional<List<Product>> getByCategory(int categoryId) {
        Optional<Producto> productos = productocrudrepo.findById(categoryId);
        return Optional.of(productMapper.toProducts(productos));
    }
```

this is the code of the interface Productrepo:

```
Optional<List<Product>> getByCategory(int categoryId);
```

this is the code of the mapStruct of the class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",uses = {CategoryMapper.class})
public interface ProductMapper {
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "idProducto",target = "productId"),
            @Mapping(source = "nombre",target = "name"),
            @Mapping(source = "idCategoria",target = "categoryId"),
            @Mapping(source = "precioVenta",target = "sellPrice"),
            @Mapping(source = "cantidadStock",target = "stock"),
            @Mapping(source = "estado",target = "active"),
            @Mapping(source = "categoria", target = "category"),
    })
    Product toProduct(Producto producto);
    List<Product> toProducts(List<Producto> productos);


    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "codigoBarras", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "compraProductos",ignore = true)
    })
    Producto toProducto(Product product);
}
```

I also try modify the method in the following ways:

> removing the Optional.of

```
public Optional<List<Product>> getByCategory(int categoryId) {
    Optional<Producto> productos = productocrudrepo.findById(categoryId);
    return (productMapper.toProducts(productos));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Optional` class has a map method which you can use to convert what it contains, without the need to extract the value from the optional. Basically it does the following: if the value is present then call the supplied function with it and return an Optional containing the function's result, otherwise return an empty Optional object.

for example with `Optional<A>`, `Optional<B>` and a method which can map `A` into `B`. What you can then do is the following:

```java
Optional<B> mapOptionalAToOptionalB(Optional<A> optA){
    return optA.map( a -> mapAtoB( a ) );
    // can also be written as optA.map( this::mapAtoB );
}
// the available method to map A into B.
B mapAtoB(A a){
  // do mapping
}
```

Concerning your repository, you probably want to use a method there that returns a list of `Producto`, based on the input `categoryId`. Currently you have `findById` in your code there which will only return a single item with that `id` and not all items with that `categoryId`. So you will probably also want to change that.

Here is an example of what you could end up with:

```java
    @Override
    public Optional<List<Product>> getByCategory(int categoryId) {
        Optional<List<Producto>> productos = productocrudrepo.getByCategory(categoryId);
        return productos.map(productMapper::toProducts);
    }
```